# How to get a list of map values from a map inside a list?

Tags: dart

Let's say I have a list that goes like this!

```
List<Map<String, String>> names = [
  {'name': 'John'},
  {'name': 'Adam'},
  {'name': 'Sean'},
  {'name': 'Shirley'},
  {'name': 'Samantha'},
];
```

How would I be able to retrieve only the list of values inside the map?

I want the output to be this:

```
List<String> names = [
  'John',
  'Adam',
  'Sean',
  'Shirley',
  'Samantha',
];
```

Comment: How should the algorithm work if there is more than one value in the map? Eg. `{'name': 'Samantha', 'lastName': 'Fox'}`. Please indicate this in the question. Should the algorithm work somehow unpredictably (in this case) or are there certain requirements?

Comment: There won't be, just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, String>> names = [
    {'name': 'John'},
    {'name': 'Adam'},
    {'name': 'Sean'},
    {'name': 'Shirley'},
    {'name': 'Samantha'},
  ];

  final onlyNames1 = names.map((map) => map.values.first).toList();
  final onlyNames2 = names.expand((map) => map.values).toList();
  print(onlyNames1); // [John, Adam, Sean, Shirley, Samantha]
  print(onlyNames2); // [John, Adam, Sean, Shirley, Samantha]
}
```

Comment: Okay, I guess I made a bad example. What if you don't know the key? Would I be able to do `map.values`?

Comment: Updated my code so it will always extract the first value of each map in the list.

Comment: Also added a way to get all values in each map.

Comment: You can also write it as a list literal: `[for (var name in names) name["name"]]`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot you can do that :)